# Deciding order of execution of three processes using Semaphore and print "AABC"

Tags: operating-system, synchronization

P1, P2, and P3 are three processes executing their respective tasks. They should synchronize among themselves using semaphores such that the string “AABC” is printed infinite times. Determine, the minimum number of semaphores required and their initial values. Also identify places where operations on that semaphore should be inserted in the code of P1, P2, and P3.
Describe how your solution works.

```
P1                   P2                   P3
while(true){         while(true){         while (true){
print(“A”);           print(“B”);          print("C");  
 }                      }                       }
```

I tried to answer this using three semaphore. But not sure whether it is correct or not. Initial  values P=1,Q=-1,R=0

```
P1                P2                 P3
while(true){      while(true){       while(true){
wait(P)           wait(Q)             wait(R)
print("A")        print("B")          print("C")
signal(P)         signal(R)           signal(P)
signal(Q)          }                   }
 }
```

Comment: Why not code it and test it?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, "AAABC" can also be generated. That is not accepted.

---

Initial values P=2, Q=-1, R=0.

P1:

```
while(true){            
wait(P)                        
print("A")                                    
signal(Q)                      
 }
```

---

P2:

```
while(true){            
wait(Q)                        
print("B")                 
signal(R)                                          
 }
```

---

P3:

```
while(true){            
wait(R)                        
print("C")                 
signal(P)                                          
 }
```